# PHP Date, adding months vis $_POST

Tags: php, database, date

Whats wrong with this code:

```
'tiercommissionexpiration' => date('Y-m + $post["billingPeriodExpiration"]-d', strtotime($post['commissionEligibilityDate'])),
```

`commissionEligibilityDate` is a date and I want to add a certain number that is entered into a text feild `$_POST['billingPeriodExpiration']` into the database 'teircommissionexpiration'

Thanks

Comment: I think you must change $post by $_POST at first.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read about PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and the [`date`](http://php.net/date) function. I have no idea what value you're trying to POST, but you cannot insert a POST value into a single-quoted string like that, and it'd be `$_POST` in any case.

```
date('Y-m' . $_POST['billingPeriodExpiration'] . '-d', ...)
date("Y-m{$_POST['billingPeriodExpiration']}-d', ...)
```

neither of which would work, but would at least be syntactically correct for parsing purposes by PHP - even though date() will fail anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the mispelling here `$post['billingPeriodExpiration']`. You should write `$_POST` and not `$post`. Anyway you have also to **double quote** the string (not single quote).

Answer (score 0):

Replace $post["billingPeriodExpiration"] with $_POST['billingPeriodExpiration']

Answer (score 0):

```
'Y-m + $post["billingPeriodExpiration"]-d'
```

should probably be

```
"Y-m + {$_POST['billingPeriodExpiration']}-d"
```

Note the double quotes and the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot embed a variable into a single apostrophe string.

Second, by $post you probably should write $_POST

And instead of theese functions, try to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
'tiercommissionexpiration' => date("Y-m + {$_POST["billingPeriodExpiration"]-d}", strtotime($_POST['commissionEligibilityDate'])),
```

Variables are not picked up inside single quotes (') and the `$_POST` var has to be caps and have the underscore.  Additionally, you should use brackets {} around array variables in strings.  (example `$n = "your name is {$user["name"]}";`)

Comment: I put in 'tiercommissionexpiration' => date("Y-m + {$post['billingPeriodExpiration']}-d", strtotime($post['commissionEligibilityDate'])) and that didn't work the date in commissionEligibilityDate is 2011-11-08 and I put 2 in the billingPeriodExpiration and I was expecting to get 2012-01-08 but I get 1969-12-31

Answer (score 0):

It's considered good practice to enclose variables in `{}` like so:

```
date("Y-m + {$post['billingPeriodExpiration']}-d")
```

This way PHP won't complain about the single quotes `''` for the array index.